# how to add text color in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4.

I know it is possible to override color of bootstrap using a variable file and importing it before bootstrap themes:

I created the following

```
$theme-colors: (
  'primary': #3892e5,
  'secondary': #27313b,
  'white': #fff,
  'success': #40b87c,
  'info': #3892e5,
  'warning': #ffb63d,
  'danger': #ff5f5f,
  'light': #f6f8fa,
  'border': #dee5ec,
  'customColor': #6e7c89,
  'dark': #25313c,
  'transparent': transparent,
);
```

But, this change the color of `bg-primary`, `bg-customColor`...

HOW do I change the default color of `text-primary` `text-customColor` ?

It doesn't work. is the only solution to target all specific text specificly in css ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your setup looks like, but it works on mine.

Basically I have a themes folder that contains all the themes I created for the site:

[image]

That's where I can override the default variables. I just copied what you posted.

```
$theme-colors: ( 
    'primary': #3892e5, 
    'secondary': #27313b, 
    'white': #fff, 
    'success': #40b87c, 
    'info': #3892e5, 
    'warning': #ffb63d, 
    'danger': #ff5f5f, 
    'light': #f6f8fa, 
    'border': #dee5ec, 
    'customColor': #6e7c89, 
    'dark': #25313c, 
    'transparent': transparent
);
```

And in another sass file I am going to use as global style for entire site (I called it `bootstrap-custom.scss`), I just import the theme, followed by the bootstrap import (either required or optional ones):

[image]

After re-compiling that scss file, it works:

[image]